# PhpStorm Vuetify autocomplete

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, phpstorm

I'm having trouble trying to get the autocomplete of vuetify components. `v-card` for example.

I'm running PhpStorm 2018.2.4 on Windows 10. I have the Vue.js plugin installed.

Comment: Hello _@h93r2398_ and welcome to Stack Overflow! This is probably something the community can help you with but we'll need a little more information first. Consider adding some more content to your question. Some improvements you might want to consider are: **(1)** What is the error message (if any) that you are receiving? **(2)** Has this been working before or is this a new error? **(3)** Share the code snippet where you're attempting to initialize the plugin. For additional information on how to ask a question in the community, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) resource.

Answer (score 1):

It can be related to Vuetify version being used; the way components are defined has been changed in 1.1+, and this new format is not yet supported ([WEB-32886](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32886)). Please follow this ticket for updates.

See https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4590#issuecomment-414300395 for possible workaround